# Terminal Commands W.R.T. LaTeX

Tags: command-line

I know there are some terminal commands with respect to LaTeX (Suppose TeX Live has been installed).

- `texdoc`
- `kpsewhich`
- `texhash`
- `mktexlsr`
- `latexdef`

And are there any other commands that you think useful? If any, please give your recommendations.

Comment: `kpsewhere` (like `kpsewhich` but lists every found file, not only the one that will end up being used)

Comment: `l3build` (for package building, testing, and installation automation)

Comment: `latexmk` for simplified compilation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of these are part of a standard TeXlive distribution, but a few aren't.

The obvious ones: `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`.

The only slightly less obvious ones: `bibtex`, `biber`, `makeindex`, `makeglossaries`, `make4ht`, `htlatex`, `tex4ebook`, `xindy`

Build automation: `latexmk`, `arara`, `rubber`

Quick log parsing: `rubber-info`

Other bibliography tools: `bibtool`, `citeproc`/`citeproc-lua`, `bbl2bib.pl`

Forward and reverse searching: `synctex`

Various converters: `dvips`, `xdvipdfmx`, `epstopdf`, `ps2pdf` (ghostscript), `pandoc`, `pdftocairo` (poppler), `convert` (imagemagick), inkscape

Tools for working with PDFs: `pdfjam`, `pdfcrop`, `qpdf`, `mutool` (mupdf), `pdffonts`/`pdfinfo` (poppler), ghostscript

Searching for fonts: `fc-list` (fontconfig), `albatross` (thanks to Skillmon)

Other tools: `latexdiff`, `texcount`

Path searching: `kpsepath`, `kpsewhich`, `kpsewhere`

Package management: `tlmgr`

I'm sure I'm forgetting a bunch.

Comment: Searching for fonts: `albatross` (it is brilliant!)

Comment: @Skillmon --- Do you get wafers with it?

Comment: @IanThompson course you don't get bloody wafers with it. Albatross!

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for pointing out albatross. I wish I had discovered it sooner! But what flavor is it?

Comment: @frabjous It's a bird, innit? It's a bloody sea bird... it's not any bloody flavour. Albatross!

Comment: The ancestor of them all: (pdf)tex.

Comment: @Teepeemm Good point. I left it off because the question says "W.R.T. LaTeX", but one can never have too many command line programs to try.

Comment: Should `detex` fit into this somewhere?